# How to rotate a sprite using his local pivot point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to rotate a sprite using his local pivot point?

This is the code i am using right now and it works fine but for the local center point.

```
private Camera myCamera;

void Start () {

    myCamera = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Camera> ();
}

void Update () {

    Vector3 pos = myCamera.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
    Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle, Vector3.forward);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **use [`Transform.RotateAround`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)** instead of directly assign local rotation.